# How to properly copy resulting jar files to target plugin directory using Maven(Tycho)?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I'm compiling my plugin projects with Maven(Tycho) and I would like to copy the resulting jar files in the plugins directory of the target.

I'm looking for the proper solution(maybe path independent tag).

Since I have already the .target file which points to the target, can I also copy the jar files to the target after build, using Maven(Tycho) ?

So far, my solution looks in the following way:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <buildDirectory>${directory}/</buildDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Is it possible to avoid this and use the target definition file to specify the path where the resulting jars should be placed ?

Comment: Why do not u use maven jar plugin directly? there is this property "outputDirectory" that can make it for you.

Comment: Because I'm building eclipse plugins, and Tycho has eclipse packaging types properties like eclipse-feature, eclipse-plugin

Comment: You lost me... Could you please clearly distinguish ".target files" and the Maven "target folder" in your question.

Comment: .target files are used to link eclipse where the development is done to target eclipse dependencies. Target folder is the plugins(or features) folder of the target eclipse